# Video rodar em uma div como background

Tags: html, html5, div

Quero fazer um vídeo rodar dentro de uma div.

Vi isso no site da [PaperCut](http://www.papercut.com/) e gostaria de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Vídeo html5/css3](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/v%c3%addeo-html5-css3)

Comment: @JulianodaSilvaBarbosa a outra pergunta é sobre um problema com o aspecto que acaba por exibir duas barras pretas (problema no ajuste do width e height), e não como colocar como background, lá o autor já sabe como fazer, o problema é especifico na manipulação do tamanho. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ambas outras respostas usaram `fixed` e `z-index` negativo com valores exagerados, pode até funcionar, mas é bem provável que irá lhe causar uma série de dores de cabeça para aplicar em um layout pronto, o ideal é usar `position: relative` + `position: absolute`, pois assim o `position: absolute` irá se adaptar ao elemento "pai", ficaria algo como:

```css
.wrap {
    /*Ajuste a largura e altura desejadas aqui*/
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;

    /*isto fará o elemento video e o .container se adaptarem ao .wrap*/
    position: relative;
}

.wrap > .bg-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; /*apenas um -1 é necessário quando se trabalha com relative + absolute, sendo pai e filho*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* evita do video passar a altura desejada do .wrap */
}
.wrap > .bg-video > video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="bg-video">
        <video autoplay src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
        Coloque o que quiser aqui <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ola amigo é fácil com html 5 
basta ter um poster do video jpg, o video em mp4 
segue um exemplo

html:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="nome-do-video.jpg" class="bg_video">
    <source src="videos/nome-do-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

css:

```
.bg_video{
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -1000;
    background: url(images/nome-do-video.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```